# search in values in array and get another value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have an array like this:

```
//the result of `dd()` function in laravel

Collection {#401 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#400 ▼
      +"tutorial_package_count": 2
      +"tutorial_package_id": 1
      +"tutorial_id": 1
    }
    1 => {#402 ▼
      +"tutorial_package_count": 1
      +"tutorial_package_id": 2
      +"tutorial_id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

suppose I have a variable as `$tutorial_id = 1`,
now I want to get value of `tutorial_package_count`. at this here I want `2`.

I dont want to use a loop.

Comment: Are you using eloquent? In that case: where('tutorial_id', 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can use [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-filter) method available for [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections):

```
$filtered = $collection->filter(function ($value, $key) use($tutorial_id) {
    return $value['tutorial_id'] == $tutorial_id;
});
$firstMatch = $filtered->first();
```